# exporting calculated GridView column to Excel gives empty values

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a GridView data with an additional calculated column. I'd like to export GridView to Excel. It returns empty values for the calculated column only. Any help will be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Here is the code I used to export to Excel.

```
   protected void ExportToExcel(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application Excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Workbook wb = Excel.Workbooks.Add(XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
        Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)Excel.ActiveSheet;
        ws.Cells.Font.Size = 10;
        Excel.ScreenUpdating = false;

        GridView3.AllowPaging = false;
        GridView3.DataBind();

        for (int i = 1; i < GridView3.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
        {
            ws.Cells[1, i] = GridView3.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
            ws.Cells[1, i].Characters.Font.Bold = true;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < GridView3.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < GridView3.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                ws.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(GridView3.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text.ToString());
            }
        }
        GridView3.AllowPaging = true;
        GridView3.DataBind();
        ws.EnableAutoFilter = true;
        ws.Range["A1", "A1"].AutoFilter(1, Type.Missing);
        ws.Columns.AutoFit();
        Excel.ScreenUpdating = true;
        Excel.Visible = true;
    }
```

Comment: You can't use Excel Interop on a web application. Each request would start a new Excel instance. Use a library like EPPlus to create real xlsx files without Excel. It can be as simple as a call to `sheet.Cells.LoadFromDataTable(table)` or `LoadFromCollection(someList)`

Comment: OK, thanks for your comments. I'll check EEPlus. It works properly with bound columns without any problem. My problem is with calculated fields in GridView. Do you have any suggestion on this?